# Update JS define property from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, defineproperty

I use the following code and I want from other module to update some property,how should I do that?

This is the **module** code(In real there is more properties...)

```
"use strict"
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true
    });
}

define("USER_PATH","oldValue");
```

Now I require it from other module and I want to update the key USER_PATH to be with "newValue".

I try to require this module and do like following which doesnt change the value in the USER_PATH,in the debugger I see the "oldValue"

```
var foo = require("theAboveModule")
foo.USER_PATH = "test";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw a `writable: true` in there:

```
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true
    });
}
```

Here's a jsbin where you can see it working: http://jsbin.com/burifi/edit?js,console